# Not able to access namespace variable in js file

Tags: javascript

a.js

```
// @global-constants
var App = {

  constant: function() {
    constant.prototype.CONST1 = 'abc';
  }

};

module.exports = App;
```

not able to access in say `b.js` using `App.constant.CONST1`, it says undefined why?

Comment: Because `App.constant` is as function and functions don't have a `CONST1` property? Simper example: `function foo() { foo.prototype.CONST1 = 42;}; console.log(foo.CONST1);` logs `undefined`.

Comment: How do i change it so that it works

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems with you code:

1.) `App.constant` would return a class(technically a function), but what you want is it's object, can be created using a `new` keyword, so it becomes, `(new App.constant).CONST1`.

2.) `constant.prototype.CONST1` would not work, because `constant` is not the name of your anonymous function, so I gave it a name `foo` and it becomes `foo.prototype.CONST1`.

the modified code:

```
var App = {
    constant: function foo() {
    foo.prototype.CONST1 = 'abc';
  }

};

console.log((new App.constant).CONST1);
```

fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ej2q1g7p/).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a set of "constants", all you need is an object:

```
// @global-constants
var App = {

  constant: {
      CONST1: 'abc';
  }

};
```

To learn more about how prototypes work (so that you know when to use them and when not), I recommend to read [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).